# Downloading a file from Javascript onclick function in python

Tags: javascript, python, html

Suppose i had an anchor tag named "Click to download" on a page which downloads a csv file when clicked

The HTML Code is

```
<span id="tag_id">
    <a class="classA" onclick="calling_an_excel_function()" href="#"> Click here to download all records.</a>
</span>
```

Actually it is calling an Javascript Onclick function and generating a csv file and the code of onclick function is

```
function calling_an_excel_function() {
    var exampleA = document.getElementById('exampleA.value');
    var exampleB = document.getElementById('exampleB.value');
    var exampleC = document.getElementById('exampleC.value');
    var exampleD = document.getElementById('exampleD.value');
    window.open('indices_main_excel.aspx?ind=' + exampleA.value + '&fromDate=' + exampleB.value + '&toDate=' + examplec.value + '&DMY=' + exampleD.value, '_blank',
'toolbar=yes,location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes ,copyhistory=no, width=800, height=600');
}
```

I can expect that in onclick function **window.open()** method is generating a new file with some values given.
Now i am unable to get **csv** file downloading **url** from the above onclick function 
Can i know how to get the csv file downloading link

Answer (score 0):

(Just guessing)

But you probably want

```
document.getElementById('exampleA');
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('exampleA.value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Window.open. Change the href to equal the file path (yes, it's coming from you server code) or use window.location. Make sure you set the content-disposition header.

I don't know how to set headers in python, but you'll want to set a header that looks like this:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"